# Python to C# TCP transfer corrupts data beyond 1523rd byte

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send a long string from a python server to a C# client. The string is 230400 bytes long. I'm both sending and receiving in chunks of 64 bytes. Server code:

```
import socket

def initialize():
  global s
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  s.bind(('', 1719))
  s.listen()

initialize()

while(1):
  sock, addr = s.accept()

  msgstr = generate_msg_string() # irrelevant

  msglen = len(msgstr)

  totalsent = 0
  while totalsent < msglen:
    sent = sock.send(msgstr[totalsent:totalsent+64])
    totalsent = totasent + sent

  sock.close()
```

Client code:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(ip, 1719);
byte[] ba = new byte[230400];
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 64
int i=0;
while(i != 230400)
{
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 64);
    buffer.CopyTo(ba, i);
    i += 64;
}
tcpClient.Close();
```

I've checked a few connections in a row - the first 1523 bytes are correct and all the rest are gibberish - at least seemingly random.

Any idea what might be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(i != 230400)
{
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 64);
    buffer.CopyTo(ba, i);
    i += 64;
}
```

The fundamental error here is assuming that `Read` read 64 bytes. It can read any of:

- 0 if the socket gets closed for any reason
- 64 bytes if that happens to be available and it chooses to
- 1-63 bytes, **just for fun**

You are not guaranteed anything other than "non-positive if the stream is closed, else at least 1 byte and no more than 64 bytes"

You **must must must** read the return value of `Read` and only process that much of the buffer. This remains the case if you switch to `Socket.Receive`, by the way.

Also - why don't you just fill `ba` in the first place, increment in the offset and decrementing the count each time?

```
int count = 230400, offset = 0, read;
byte[] ba = new byte[count];
while(count > 0 && (read=stream.Read(ba, offset, count)) > 0)
{
    offset += read;
    count -= read;
}
if(read!=0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
```

Comment: This did indeed help. My received string is now perfectly correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I hurried with the question.

Changing TcpClient to Socket fixed the problem. The approach remained the same.

Comment: @MarcGravell is correct - fix it by not ignoring the result returned by read().